# Python remote directory browsing Server-Client

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, client-server, directory-browsing

I'm  working on python GUI-application with Tkinter to exchange files between two local PC `Local Client` and `Local Server` using the `socket` library ([Local file transfer](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_network_programming_server_client_file_transfer.php)). What I want to do is to browse remotely the `Server` folders  from the `Client GUI` to choose a file then send it to the `Client` computer.

Right now, I'm running the `Client` and the `Server` on the same machine.
The appliccation works as follows:

-After I run the `Server` script ,it waits for an incoming connection.

-I run the `Client` script (GUI) on the same machine, then I browse folders using this function :

```
def browser(self):
    options = {
                "mustexist": False,
                "initialdir": '/media', #default path
                "title": 'Choose a directory'
              }
    #this will open a dialogue window to select the desired directory
    self.browsePath = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(**options)
    self.path_Etr.delete(0,END)
    self.path_Etr.insert(0,self.browePath)
```

-The `Client` send the chosen file path (text) to the `Server`

-The `Server` send back the file

That process works fine one the same machine (because the `Client` and the `Server` had same directory-tree) .

But how to do that on separate machines , I wonder if there's a way to receive the `Server` directory-tree and vizualize it on `Client` GUI or somthing else?

I hope my question is claire !

Comment: If you are wondering why this question is getting so many down votes its because you have not provided any code. You should provide code you have attempted to use and ask about a specific problem you have run into. Stack Overflow is not for broad questions like this. That being said, sure there is a way. Tkinter is a GUI library you real question should probably be related to "Is it possible for python to read files on a separate computer" followed up with what research you have done so far and what attempt you have made to do this.

Comment: tkanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a server on the remote computer, such that when it is sent a directory over `sockets`, it will send back the contents. On the other computer, you would need a client. If there is no predetermined server/client, have all computers be servers, until told otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . I'm sorry , my question wasn't claire  (i had just modified it)